# Using GetCustomAttributes to get all attributes but DataMemberAttributes

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I am trying to get custom attributes from a PropertyInfo object, but I am trying to avoid getting DataMemberAttributes. I run into compiler error 'cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo'" with the following code:

```
PropertyInfo myProperty = GetMyProperty(myObject);

object[] myAttributes= fromProperty.GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(a => !Attribute.IsDefined(a, typeof(DataMemberAttribute)));
```

What would be the correct lambda syntax?

Comment: It's not clear why you're calling `Attribute.IsDefined`. Don't you just want `Where (a => !(a is DataMemberAttribute)`? A [mcve] would really help clarify things...